# Flutter AppsFlyer build for Android exception

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, appsflyer

flutter build apk

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done 13.5s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin appsflyer_sdk...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done 2.0s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'appsflyer_sdk'.

Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run wit
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this exception you must update version of build:gradle classpath in you app/build.gradle to 4.0.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

And Open YourProject > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties and replace

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-version-number-all.zip
```

With

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```